# How can I solve "Your connection to 192.*.*.* is encrypted with obsolete cryptography"

Tags: apache-httpd, openssl, cryptography

I just set up my apache server with SSL installed on it, and everything is perfect except that when I open the page with https:// I get the following message when I click the padlock next to the address bar in chrome: "***Your connection to 192.*.*.* is encrypted with obsolete cryptography***"

I have an Apache Server version:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Mar 12 2015 15:07:19
```

And SSL:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
```

This is the configuration I have in my httpd.conf file:

```
SSLCipherSuite AES128+EECDH:AES128+EDH
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
# Requires Apache >= 2.4
SSLCompression off
SSLUseStapling on
SSLStaplingCache "shmcb:logs/stapling-cache(150000)"

#Cipher directives end here.
<VirtualHost *:443>
    Servername 192.80.91.70
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/examplei/app.example.com


   SSLEngine On


    ErrorLog /var/www/html/SSLerror.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/SSLrequests.log combined
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/example.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/example.key
</VirtualHost>
```

**Update:**

I didn't noticed, but I get this message on the padlock next to the address bar only when I go to the IP address of my server and the screen of "This connection is not private" appears. Then, when I click on *proceed I understand the risks* I click the padlock again and now it says that is encrypted with modern cryptography. So I don't understand if this is the expected behavior or what's going on.

Comment: Probably your certificate was signed using SHA1 instead of SHA2.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I used this command to generate my certificate: sudo openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -keyout example.key -out example.crt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside: @CodesInChaos Chrome says "outdated security settings", NOT "obsolete cryptography", for SHA1 cert past end of year.

The **"Your connection is not private"** page you added is actually the important symptom. It isn't caused by crypto settings, it's caused if the **cert cannot be validated**, because it is selfsigned (which is your case with `openssl req -new -x509`) or it is signed by a CA not in the truststore (or your server wasn't configured to send the chain certs needed to link to the root in the truststore) or the name in the cert doesn't match the hostname. On testing I see the "not private" page **also** shows "obsolete cryptography" without the details normally present in Connection info, even though the initial connection did use a cipher Chrome does consider modern (in my case GCM). Perhaps this is because Chrome actually drops the connection while the "not private" page is displayed, so there isn't really *any* crypto in effect at that time.